# Why AsyncStorage gives an empty array when storing array of objects in react native

Tags: react-native

I have react native app with method to fill an array of objects :

```
  getArticlesCategoryStrogae= () => {
  try {
  global.arrayOfCategory=[];
  getMenusideGategory().then((data)=>
    {
    //some code to fill the array

    });
 AsyncStorage.setItem('arrayOfCategoryStorage', JSON.stringify(global.arrayOfCategory));
      } 
  catch (error) {  throw error  }
    }
```

If I make  `console.log("1",arrayOfCategory)` I got :

[image]

I want to store it using AsyncStorage.

```
  
  AsyncStorage.getItem('arrayOfCategoryStorage').then((value) => {
         if(value!=null)
     {
     console.log("2",JSON.parse(value));
     }
     });
```

Why I am getting an empty array for `console.log("2",JSON.parse(value));` ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is probably because your getMenusideGategory() method is an asynchronous operation, so when it returns, AsyncStorage.setItem has been executed. You should put AsyncStorage.setItem into then of getMenusideGategory(). For example:

```
getArticlesCategoryStrogae = () => {
  try {
    global.arrayOfCategory = []
    getMenusideGategory().then((data) => {
      //some code to fill the array
      AsyncStorage.setItem('arrayOfCategoryStorage', JSON.stringify(global.arrayOfCategory))
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

By the way, I recommend you an open source library [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md). After the binding of persistent objects and AsyncStorage is completed, you can more easily access AsyncStorage synchronously, and can also store and retrieve objects, strings or Boolean data,which can improve work efficiency.

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       isShow: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };
   
  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously
       
       // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
       console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };
  
  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```

Comment: Ok thanks man, yes maybe the reason is related to async, still i can not store it . Ii is nested array of array objects, i store each item separately and it works fine.